# About installing Scala 2.11.4?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to install the latest Scala version 2.11.4 on my machine but the instructions on their website are cryptic to me. Can any one explain how to install it step by step?

Comment: USC has 2.9. Is that not sufficient to use it? edit: there is also a PPA for 2.10 https://launchpad.net/~jens-braeuer/+archive/ubuntu/ppa Not for 2.11 yet so would 2.10 suffice?

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to install Scala would be to use the *.deb* installation file. On the [download page](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/) you can see the newest stable version. Then go to the [All Downloads](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html) page and find that version (or [Scala 2.11.4](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.4.html)). Scroll down to the bottom of that version's page and look for *scala-2.11.4.deb* (or the appropriate version) and download it.

If you're comfortable with the command line, you can install the downloaded Scala *deb* with:

```
sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.4.deb
```

Otherwise, you're going to have to install [GDebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/) through either the Ubuntu Software Center, or via a terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Once GDebi is installed, you can double click *scala-2.11.4.deb* in your file browser which will open the package installer. Finally, click "Install Package", and your new version of Scala will be installed.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out that they provide .deb files. However, you don't need gdebi, it's as simple as: sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.4.deb

Comment: I couldn't find them at that link, but they are at the archives page: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/

Answer (score 11):

Just download `scala.deb` and install it:

```
sudo apt-get remove scala-library scala
wget http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.11.6.deb
sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.6.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.4.deb should be sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.6.deb

Comment: I don't think scala needs to be installed twice again using `sudo apt-get install scala`. dpkg will install it.

Comment: @PraveenSripati 
I'm not sure why he put `sudo apt-get install scala`, as `sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.6.deb` is sufficent but installing the `scala.deb` from the site I think is better than using `sudo apt-get install scala`, as the official repositories are more up to date

Comment: I got dpkg-deb: error: `scala-2.11.6.deb' is not a debian format archive

Answer (score 3):

Installing scala 2.11.4 or any other version that is not in the Ubuntu repository or a PPA (mind though: scala will require JAVA and I assume you have this installed already. See the [ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) if you have not).

- [download](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/) the file.
- Extract the contents to somewhere on your system. I would opt for /opt/scala/. Something like:

  tar xvfz ~/Downloads/scala-2.11.4.tgz /opt/
    mv /opt/scala-2.11.4/ /opt/scala/
- The readme in "docs" state you can run scala from the bin directory:

> Installation
>
> Decompress the archive and run the above commands directly from `bin`
>   directory. We recommend adding the full path of the `bin` directory to
>   the `PATH` environment variable.

- ... where you have the following tools:

  ```
  - scala       Scala interactive interpreter
  - scalac      Scala compiler
  - fsc         Scala resident compiler
  - scaladoc    Scala API documentation generator
  - scalap      Scala classfile decoder
  ```

  So you would do

  ```
  cd /opt/scala
  scala
  ```

  to open the interpreter.

---

- Regarding the PATH mentioned in the read me:

  Add Scala to your $PATH by adding this line to `.profile` inside your home directory

  ```
  PATH="$PATH:/opt/scala/bin"
  ```

  Mind that the path name needs to be named after what you extracted it too. Adding it would stop the need to do `cd /opt/scala/` and you can envoke `scala` from anywhere on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the installation [instructions](http://scala-lang.org/download/install.html) on scala-lang.org are brief and assume a certain level of proficiency with setting up of environment variables. This assumption is also present in most of the answers here or on stackoverflow. another reson I wanted to add my answer is that there are no more .deb files available for downloading from scala-lang.org.

Recently I have successfully installed Scala 2.11.7 on my machine following these steps. It was a fresh Scala installation and Java 1.8 was already present.

1. Downloaded scala-2.11.7.tgz from http://www.scala-lang.org/download/ to my Downloads directory.
2. Navigate to the downloads directory and unpack the archive:

   ```
   sudo tar xvfz scala-2.11.4.tgz
   ```
3. Move the unpacked directory to the directory indicated in the instructions:

   ```
   mv scala-2.11.7 /usr/local/share/scala
   ```
4. Set the environment variables permanently. As indicated in the question on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904186/3052217), and used by other software package installations, (e. g. I found Anaconda Python as the last automatic edit on it), one of reliable ways of doing it is by editing .bashrc file or adding these variables to the PATH directly with these commands:

   ```
   export 'SCALA_HOME="/usr/local/share/scala"' >> ~/.bashrc

   export 'PATH="$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Reload the shell for the changes to take effect:

   ```
   exec $SHELL
   ```

Now you can start Scala REPL from the command line by typing:

```
scala
```

Comment: I guess you don't need `sudo` in step 2, but maybe in step 3. And you also don't need sudo for editing your `.bashrc`

Comment: One more thing to have in mind is that your sudo password is valid for 15 more min after the first submission. From  Ubuntu docs,  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo .

Comment: I just edited by .bashrc directly with the line:   export PATH="/opt/scala/scala-2.12.1/bin:$PATH"